# How do you get correct variable names in babel-node debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging, babeljs, babel-node

```
npm i babel-cli babel-preset-env
echo '{"presets": ["env"]}' > .babelrc
printf "import u from 'util';\ndebugger;\nconsole.log(u);\n" > foo.es
babel-node --inspect-brk foo.es
```

Continue to breakpoint <kbd>F8</kbd> and inspect `u`. You get a `ReferenceError: u is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple
```

Then, add it to your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple", {
       "noMangle": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

With `noMangle: true` the original variable names are preserved in sourcemaps.

Then run:

```
babel-node --inspect foo.es
```

Your variable `u` is there :)